# How to download multiple am4charts with layout in one PDF file?

Tags: amcharts

I want to export multiple am4charts with layout in one PDF like it was in V3
https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/tutorials/exporting-pdf-with-multiple-charts-and-related-info/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the new tutorial [how to generate a multi-content PDF](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/generating-multi-content-pdf-export/).

You can add another chart as `extraSprites` from version 4.2.0 as in:

```
chart.exporting.extraSprites.push(chart2);
```

Check more about [how to add an extra element here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/exporting/#Including_external_elements).

**Previous Recommendation**

I recommend you to check the answer for this issue: https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/743

amCharts uses [PDFMake](http://pdfmake.org/) to generate PDFs, which allows you to assemble PDF as you whish.

Please check a simpler example how your code could look like:

```
// Use this method to call the export functionality
let exportCharts = async (charts) => {

    // Map chats to images
    let images = await Promise.all(charts.map(async (chart) => {

        return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            let getImage = () => {
                resolve(chart.exporting.getImage('png'));
            }

            // Get the image if the chart is ready
            if (chart.isReady())
                getImage();
            // Get the image when the chart is ready
            else
                chart.events.on('ready', () => getImage());
            });
        }));

        // Begin PDF layout
        const layout = {
            content: []
        };

        // Add charts
        layout.content = images.map((image) => {

        return {
            image: image,
            fit: [523, 300]
        };
    });

    // Finally, download our PDF
    charts[0].exporting.pdfmake.then(function(pdfMake) {
        pdfMake.createPdf(layout).download("amcharts4.pdf");
    });
}

// Call exports with all the charts you want exported
exportCharts([chart1, chart2]);
```

```js
/**
 * ---------------------------------------
 * This demo was created using amCharts 4.
 * 
 * For more information visit:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/
 * 
 * Documentation is available at:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/
 * ---------------------------------------
 */

// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end
  
// Create chart instance
var chart1 = am4core.create('chart-1', am4charts.XYChart3D);

// Add data
chart1.data = [{
  "country": "USA",
  "visits": 4025
}, {
  "country": "China",
  "visits": 1882
}, {
  "country": "Japan",
  "visits": 1809
}, {
  "country": "Germany",
  "visits": 1322
}, {
  "country": "UK",
  "visits": 1122
}, {
  "country": "France",
  "visits": 1114
}, {
  "country": "India",
  "visits": 984
}, {
  "country": "Spain",
  "visits": 711
}, {
  "country": "Netherlands",
  "visits": 665
}, {
  "country": "Russia",
  "visits": 580
}, {
  "country": "South Korea",
  "visits": 443
}, {
  "country": "Canada",
  "visits": 441
}, {
  "country": "Brazil",
  "visits": 395
}, {
  "country": "Italy",
  "visits": 386
}, {
  "country": "Australia",
  "visits": 384
}, {
  "country": "Taiwan",
  "visits": 338
}, {
  "country": "Poland",
  "visits": 328
}];

// Create axes
let categoryAxis = chart1.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "country";
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.rotation = 270;
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.hideOversized = false;
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 20;
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.horizontalCenter = "right";
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.verticalCenter = "middle";
categoryAxis.tooltip.label.rotation = 270;
categoryAxis.tooltip.label.horizontalCenter = "right";
categoryAxis.tooltip.label.verticalCenter = "middle";

let valueAxis = chart1.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.title.text = "Countries";
valueAxis.title.fontWeight = "bold";

// Create series
var series = chart1.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries3D());
series.dataFields.valueY = "visits";
series.dataFields.categoryX = "country";
series.name = "Visits";
series.tooltipText = "{categoryX}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";
series.columns.template.fillOpacity = .8;

var columnTemplate = series.columns.template;
columnTemplate.strokeWidth = 2;
columnTemplate.strokeOpacity = 1;
columnTemplate.stroke = am4core.color("#FFFFFF");

columnTemplate.adapter.add("fill", (fill, target) => {
  return chart1.colors.getIndex(target.dataItem.index);
})

columnTemplate.adapter.add("stroke", (stroke, target) => {
  return chart1.colors.getIndex(target.dataItem.index);
})

chart1.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart1.cursor.lineX.strokeOpacity = 0;
chart1.cursor.lineY.strokeOpacity = 0;

// Create chart instance
var chart2 = am4core.create('chart-2', am4charts.PieChart);

// Add data
chart2.data = [ {
  "country": "Lithuania",
  "litres": 501.9
}, {
  "country": "Czech Republic",
  "litres": 301.9
}, {
  "country": "Ireland",
  "litres": 201.1
}, {
  "country": "Germany",
  "litres": 165.8
}, {
  "country": "Australia",
  "litres": 139.9
}, {
  "country": "Austria",
  "litres": 128.3
}, {
  "country": "UK",
  "litres": 99
}, {
  "country": "Belgium",
  "litres": 60
}, {
  "country": "The Netherlands",
  "litres": 50
} ];

// Add and configure Series
var pieSeries = chart2.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
pieSeries.dataFields.value = "litres";
pieSeries.dataFields.category = "country";
pieSeries.slices.template.stroke = am4core.color("#fff");
pieSeries.slices.template.strokeWidth = 2;
pieSeries.slices.template.strokeOpacity = 1;

// This creates initial animation
pieSeries.hiddenState.properties.opacity = 1;
pieSeries.hiddenState.properties.endAngle = -90;
pieSeries.hiddenState.properties.startAngle = -90;

// Disable labels
pieSeries.labels.template.disabled = true;
pieSeries.ticks.template.disabled = true;

// Use this method to call the export functionality
let exportCharts = async (charts) => {

  // Map chats to images
  let images = await Promise.all(charts.map(async (chart) => {

    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      let getImage = () => {
        resolve(chart.exporting.getImage('png'));
      }

      // Get the image if the chart is ready
      if (chart.isReady())
        getImage();
      // Get the image when the chart is ready
      else
        chart.events.on('ready', () => getImage());
    });
  }));

  // Begin PDF layout
  const layout = {
    content: []
  };

  // Add charts
  layout.content = images.map((image) => {

    return {
      image: image,
      fit: [523, 300]
    };
  });

  // Finally, download our PDF
  charts[0].exporting.pdfmake.then(function(pdfMake) {
    pdfMake.createPdf(layout).download("amcharts4.pdf");
  });
}

document.getElementById('print-to-pdf').addEventListener('click', () => {

  // Call exports with all the charts you want exported
  exportCharts([chart1, chart2]);
  
});
```

```css
.ui.segment {
  padding: 0;
}

body > .ui.container {
  margin-top: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 4em;
}

body > .ui.container > .ui.segment {
  height: 36em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/viewport-action@0.2.1/dist/viewportAction.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui container">

  <button id="print-to-pdf" class="ui blue button">Print</button>
  
  <div id="chart-1" class="ui segment">
    <div class="ui active loader"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="chart-2" class="ui segment">
    <div class="ui active loader"></div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: download("amcharts4.pdf") is not working for me. But .open() is working fine.

Comment: @Saumya, I updated the code and also added a working example.

Comment: charts[0].exporting.pdfmake.then(function(pdfMake) {
        pdfMake.createPdf(layout).download("amcharts4.pdf");
});

code is not working for me, getting "TypeError: Cannot set property vfs of [object Module] which has only a getter" error. Looks like existing problem in  amchart 4 version. 

https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/901